# How to extend the concept of Crossed G-set?

Tags: abstract-algebra

A crossed $G$-set is a $G$-set $X$, where $G$ is a group, together with a morphism of $G$-sets $\phi: X \to G$, where $G$ acts on itself by conjugation. A union of an arbitrary set of conjugacy classes in a group $G$ is a basic example. If we replace $G$ by a field $F$, I want to know whether there exists an equivalent concept for this version?